# Should I choose <button> element or css buttons?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

Ok, here's the thing. 
I've done a webpage which contains forms and so I added buttons as  elements and this works great. I created their own css classes and use graphics as background images for each of them. All working great (these are submit buttons btw)

Anyway, I've also got a jQuery script from before that takes all a href hyperlinks and add content from a set div from an external file and adds to a div in my current page, all in one animation. But this would probably not work with form buttons?

In any case I need to be able to have these buttons work as traditional hyperlinks anyway. So what do I do?

I thought about using css-buttons alltogether, but I'm not able to have them stack vertically. Using float left or right just put the buttons outside of their parent containers (probably a different fix for that).

But in any case, using css buttons, that wouldn't work as a submit button for the forms anyway would it? Should I perhaps use both form buttons and css buttons? What do you do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<button>` elements.

You should never use links to submit data, users with javascript disabled won't be able to use them, crawlers can submit data accidentally, etc...

Comment: thanks for the edit meagar, didn't know how to do that inline code :)

Comment: No worries, I had hoped you'd pick up on it :)

Comment: Another reason for using a `<button>` is that it works better with assistive technologies like screen readers.

Comment: In conclusion, both <button> elements and CSS-buttons are what I really want then? Each for their own purpose? What are the differences between <button> and <input> anyway? Should I use button specifically?

Comment: you can have html inside a button element `<button type="submit" value="save"><img src="smiley.jpg" />Send us your data</button>` I say just make the buttons look like buttons and the links look like links :)

Comment: Yeah, I can add images to buttons. And even styling the buttons completely. And that's basically what I'm doing. But I also need href buttons as well. And that was the problem, which one do I chose? Both? Or just one of them :)

Comment: If your button submits user supplied data use a button, if it doesn't use href.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed to know :)